# identity.loginName print on the pdf file

Tags: javascript, pdf

hi all i have adobe acrobat 8.0 v. 
and im trying to put on the page the line that say Printed By "userName and Loging Name"
by using javascript code
im trying this code

```
name = identity.name;    userName = identity.loginName;
name.value = util.printd();
userName.value = util.printd();
```

what shold i do for showing on the pdf file the details?

Comment: `util.printd()` prints what's inside the brackets. Does a related question on the Adobe forums help? http://forums.adobe.com/thread/734547

Answer (score 0):

`printd` formats dates, it doesn't write anything to the page.

I don't believe you can actually output text into the document with Acrobat scripting at all. You might be able to do what you want by adding a form field to the document and writing a value to that:

```
getField('someField').value= 'Printed by '+identity.name+' ('+identity.loginName+')';
```

Comment: hi bobince my text fiald name is userName , so i need to put getField('userName') ? this is the line i need to wrote in the javascript file

Comment: i found this code to but  
var sNoticeField = "Text1"; // name of field for printed notice
var sText =  "Printed by "; // date lead in text
sText += ' at '; // time lead in

//sText +=identity.name;
//sText +=identity.loginName ; 
this.getField(sNoticeField).value = sText; // set the field value
the two lines thats are commend dosend printed to the screen what is the problem

Comment: Have you added a form field with the right name to the document? Acrobat can only write content to form fields.

Comment: what form ? identity.loginName ? when i execute the pdf i got "Printed by at".my fiald name is Text1

Comment: Have you got `Printed by at` coming out into a form field on the page? If so, you should be able to add other properties into that text string. It's difficult to see but from the code pasted into your comment above it looks like you have commented out the bits that are supposed to add in the username?

Comment: yes u right i got the "Printed by at". when the lines was comment but when i uncomment the page didnt get the extra details. its maybe becuese im using acrobat 8?